# Should the usage of reflection be avoided in Go?

Tags: reflection, go, interface

I'm new to `Go` and also new to the concept of `reflection`, but **should** and **can** the usage of [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package be avoided in `Go`? Is there a scenario where `reflect` is unavoidable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few problem domains where reflection makes it easier to write reusable libraries:

- marshalling/unmarshalling, plenty of examples in the standard library, e.g. `encoding/json`, `encoding/xml`
- formatting, e.g. `text/template`, `html/template`, `fmt.Printf`.

However there is a price you pay for using reflection:

- compile time errors become runtime errors (e.g. `fmt.Printf("%d", stringVariable)`)
- performance becomes worse

Very often an alternative solution exists that do not require reflection such as code generation, that is used by marshalling libraries like protobuf or thrift.

I agree with @volker that you should use reflection only when you know that it will simplify already existing code and aware of all downsides.

Comment: Thanks for feedback kostya :)

Answer (score 10):

You should avoid reflection.

Some packages (e.g. fmt) cannot be implemented without reflection as you cannot typeswitch on all existing and upcoming types.

If you are new to Go: Keep away from reflection.